# How do I get into edit mode as shown in this video?

Tags: interface, versions

I'm trying to follow along with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNHw4-DEpzE), but I seem to have a different version of Blender than is being used in the video, and some parts of the UI react very differently.  At timestamp 9:57, the presenter selects an object with modifiers applied, then presses Tab to enter Edit mode, where he gets a graph of all the vertices and edges overlaid upon the object.

When I press it, I get a completely different view:
[image]

I'm using Blender 2.90.  No idea what the tutorial is using, but it's a year and a half old and I can only assume they changed the UI around sometime since this was posted.  I have some minimal experience in Blender, but not enough to figure out what I need to do here to continue to follow the tutorial.  Can anyone explain how to get to the view shown in the video on modern Blender?

Comment: Since you haven't actually said which tutorial you're trying to follow or given a link to it, it's impossible to help!

Comment: @JohnEason Gah!  My mistake.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have added the modifiers, but you have not applied them yet. That's why it looks different. The transparent cube on your screenshot is the unmodified mesh. The sphere is the result of the Subdivision Surface modifier. The Displacement modifier is disabled in Edit Mode (see icons of the modifiers).

In Blender 2.9x the apply button of modifiers has been removed. It's now hidden in a drop down menu. Apply the modifiers and it should look like in the video.

[image: apply cloth modifier (2.9)]

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  I figured it was something like that, but I had no idea where to find the "apply modifiers" command.  I kept looking for it in the context menus in the hierarchy pane!

Comment: That tutorial was done in Blender version 2.79. A lot changed when 2.8 was released including the use of the outliner (top right). In your case it looks as if the object was duplicated at some stage and one object had the modifiers applied. You can see this in the outliner. The object with the modifiers applied is MeteorTut01.001 and the one with them unapplied is MeteorTut01. In 2.79 you used Layers clicking in the box on the bottom toolbar and you can see the object hilight change in the outliner when he clicks on a layer. In 2.8 that system is replaced by Collections in the outliner.